# Using regex to to replace only if the string filename has .jpg or .png extension

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a huge filename string list, using the regex to to replace only if the string filename has .jpg or .png extension

Means to say if the filename is

`Scene.jpg` then expected result is `IMG_Scene.jpg`.

`Scenejpgx.docx` then expected result is `Scenejpgx.docx` itself

I tried with

```
str.replace(/^/i,"IMG_");
```

but this replaces every strings.

Comment: Use: `str.replace(/^(?=.*\.(?:jpg|png)$)/, 'IMG_')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
.replace(/.*\.(?:jpg|png)$/i, 'IMG_$&')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/blKFMp/2)

**Details**

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\.`  - a dot
- `(?:jpg|png)` - `jpg` or `png`
- `$` - end of string.

The `$&` is the backreference to the whole match, so `IMG_$&` basically prepends the match with `IMG_`.

See JavaScript demo:

```js
const strings = ['Scene.jpg','Scenejpgx.docx'];
const re = /.*\.(?:jpg|png)$/i;
strings.forEach( x =>
  console.log(x, '=>', x.replace(re, 'IMG_$&'))
);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It works great in general. But in my case, I need to replace strings that only starts with a special word, like replacing ```/uploads/ .... .png``` with ```/uploads/large_ .... .png```. I'm not enough knowledge about **regex**. Could you please tell me the suitable regex for that kind of replacement?

Comment: @hamid-davodi See https://regex101.com/r/blKFMp/4, `.replace(/^(\/uploads\/(?:.*\/)?)(.*\.(?:jpg|png))$/, "$1large_$2")`